# ArgoCD ignoreDifferences not working for openshift machinesets with kyverno mutation

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, argocd, gitops

The machineSet im deploying has the keyword CLUSTERID injected in several places of the manifest.
Kyverno will mutate each instance of the word for the actual cluster name.
if i deploy it "manually" using helm install it works great, but when deployed by ArgoCD it gets created > mutated > Out of Sync > Deleted > re-created in an endless loop.

i have tried removing all the jsonPointers in order to ignore the whole api-resoource and also add Kyverno as filedManager. none worked.

```
  ignoreDifferences:
  - group: "*"
    kind: "*"
    managedFieldsManagers:
    - kyverno
```

This is the result of running `helm install kyverno-machineset  -f ../../myvalues.yml ./ocp-machineset --dry-run --debug` (to show where is CLUSTERID injected by the helm template)

```
# Source: ocp-machineset/templates/machineset.yaml
apiVersion: machine.openshift.io/v1beta1
kind: MachineSet
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    machine.openshift.io/cluster-api-cluster: CLUSTERID
  name: CLUSTERID-kyverno-worker
  namespace: openshift-machine-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      machine.openshift.io/cluster-api-cluster: CLUSTERID
      machine.openshift.io/cluster-api-machineset: CLUSTERID-kyverno-worker
      
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        machine.openshift.io/cluster-api-cluster: CLUSTERID
        machine.openshift.io/cluster-api-machine-role: kyverno
        machine.openshift.io/cluster-api-machine-type: kyverno
        machine.openshift.io/cluster-api-machineset: CLUSTERID-kyverno-worker
      
    spec:
      metadata:
      
        labels:
          node-role.kubernetes.io/kyverno: ""
      
    
      taints:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/kyverno
        effect: NoSchedule
    
      providerSpec:
        value:
          apiVersion: vsphereprovider.openshift.io/v1beta1
          credentialsSecret:
            name: vsphere-secret
          diskGiB: 200
          kind: VSphereMachineProviderSpec
          memoryMiB: 76000
          metadata:
            creationTimestamp: null
          network:
            devices:
            - networkName: LAB-NET
          numCPUs: 16
          numCoresPerSocket: 16
        
          snapshot: ""
          template: CLUSTERID-rhcos
          userDataSecret:
            name: worker-user-data
          workspace:
            datacenter: lab
            datastore: vsphere_openshift
            folder: /folder/to/datastore
            resourcePool: /folder/to/resourcepool
            server: vcenter.lab.example.com
```

this is my ArgoCD app.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: app-worker-nodes-kyverno-test
  labels:
    clusterName: lab1
    owner: "John Doe"
spec:
  project: project
  source:
    chart: "ocp-machineset"
    repoURL: 'https://repo.example.com'
    targetRevision: ^0.1.1-0
    helm:
      values: |-
        cluster: "CLUSTERID"
        vmware:
          datacenter: "lab"
          datastore: "vsphere_openshift"
          folder: " /folder/to/datastore"
          resourcePool: "/folder/to/resourcepool"
          server: "vcenter.lab.example.com"
        networkName: "LAB-NET"

        machineset:
          name: kyverno
          storage: 200
          cpu: 16
          memory: 76000
          replicas: 1
          isDefaultWorker: false
  destination:
    server: 'https://lab.cluster.example.com'
    namespace: openshift-machine-api
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: false
      selfHeal: true
    syncOptions:
    - Replace=true
  ignoreDifferences:
  - group: machine.openshift.io
    kind: MachineSet
    namespace: openshift-machine-api
    jsonPointers:
    - /metadata/name
    - /metadata/labels/machine.openshift.io~1cluster-api-cluster
    - /spec/selector/matchLabels/machine.openshift.io~1cluster-api-cluster
    - /spec/selector/matchLabels/machine.openshift.io~1cluster-api-machineset
    - /spec/template/metadata/labels/machine.openshift.io~1cluster-api-cluster
    - /spec/template/metadata/labels/machine.openshift.io~1cluster-api-machineset
    - /spec/template/spec/providerSpec/value/template
```

As you can see this makes ArgoCD think the resource deployed to the cluster doesn't exist in the source manifest and should be deleted (trash bin) and the one defined in the manifest (CLUSTERID) is missing (ghost)

[image: ArgoCD doesnt recognize ignoreDifference]

ArgoCD should ignore the differences in the fields listed under `ignoreDifferences` and keep the resrouces as Sync & Healthy.